# One row with 3 cells and row below with 2 cells

Tags: html, html-table

I can't figure out how to use colspan for accomplishing this rows and cells:

```
__________________________________________
|           ||             ||            |
|  CONTENT  ||  CONTENT    ||  CONTENT   |
==========================================
|                  ||                    |
|     CONTENT      ||       CONTENT      |
|                  ||                    |
------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>CONTENT</td>
    <td colspan="2">CONTENT</td>
    <td>CONTENT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">CONTENT</td>
    <td colspan="2">CONTENT</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```